# Get package names and class names for all applications

Tags: android, class, package

Does anyone know the class name and package name for any of these applications:

youtube
facebook
amazon mp3
google talk
camera maps
text message
dialer/phone
launcher
android market
messaging
contacts
Social Networking
Advanced Task Killer

I'm trying to make buttons to open these applications.  Surely there must be an easier way than figuring out the package and class name for every application.  If there is let me know how to do it.
Thanks! :)

Comment: do you wish to get all information regarding install app?

Comment: That would be nice too.  But if you give me code for that can you include the entire java file and the entire manifest  and xml files.

Answer (score 3):

```
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String classname = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.d("Applist ",appname + "   " + pname + "   " + classname + "   " + versionCode);

    }
}





public ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
     Log.d("AppNo", "Inside Packages"); 
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    Log.d("AppNo", "no of apps "+max); 
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();

    }
    return apps;
}

public ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);



        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.classname = p.applicationInfo.className;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

        Intent app=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(p.packageName);


            if(app!=null){
                dleteintent(app,newInfo.appname, newInfo.icon);
                res.add(newInfo);
        }

    }
    return res;
```

}

Using PakageInfo you can get package name, application Name but not sure about application class name

Using this example you can list all applications install in your device and can get there information.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the package name and many other parts of the AndroidManifest.xml by pulling the development tools from the emulator, and install it on the device with the requested applications. you can execute these commands at the command prompt to do this.

while the emulator is connected, run:

`/path-to-android-sdk/platform-tools/adb pull /system/app/DevelopmentTools.apk`

disconnect the emulator, connect the device, and run:

`/path-to-android-sdk/platform-tools/adb install DevelopmentTools.apk`