# How to run installed app when a user clicks a button

Tags: android, package-managers

I created a button, and I want when a user clicks this button. It should run an installed app from my device (such as Maps). This is my code (button is aupeo)

```
aupeo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
                .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

                for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                         //Don't know how to get app's info to call it.
                }
            }

        });
```

I don't know how to get app's info, call and run app.

Comment: Common way is to pass an Intent, and android lets you pick which app to launch for that intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 aupeo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                  Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setClassName("com.xxxx.your_package_name",
                        "com.xxxx.your_class_name");

                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Such as Google Maps,how to call this

Comment: I think you has mistake,i want to run INSTALLED app when click button,not run class.

Comment: so.. suppose.. your phone has..number of application now one button click you want to all installed app run....k

Comment: I just want 1 specify app runs when i click button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8729352/1339473. so get all package name and list out and select one of them.. this on is help you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21308/discussion-between-altaf-and-phucloi89)